# Javascript based game

Tags: javascript

So i've been trying make a game where you bet money and if you win you get a profit, to win you must guess the correct outcome of the dice (6 sided) if you do you get your money + profit, i have been kind of successful but it dosen't pay you.

if you could help me fix this thanks. WEBSITE: http://csgodice.net16.net/dice.php

- EDIT : Added the whole code!
- EDIT: Things still broken with a new error: game is not defined.

  CSGODice.net

  ```
  <div id="header">
      <div id="navbar">
          <a class="nav1" href="/"><bold>HOME</bold></a>
          <a class="nav2" href="dice.php"><bold>DICE</bold></a>
          <a class="nav3" href="support.php">SUPPORT</a>
          <a class="balance" href="#">Gems: 0</a>
  <div id="steamLogon">
      <?php

          require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';

          if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

          loginbutton("small"); //login button

          }  else {

          include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
          //Protected content
          logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
      } 
      ?>
  </div>
      </div>
  <div id="dicelogo">
      <a href="/">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>
      </a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="dicegame">
    <div id="diceholder">
      <h1>
        <div id="diceroller">
          <span id="value" class="lable_value">0</span>
          <script>
          var m = document.getElementsByClassName("balance");
          var o = document.getElementsById("diceroller");
          var w = document.getElementsByClassName("winchance");

          var uc = document.getElementsByClassName("userchoice").value;

          var b = document.getElementsById("bet").value;
          var p = document.getElementsById("profit");

          function game(event){
          var wn = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
          o.innerText = wn;
          if(uc.value == wn) {
              m.innerText = m.innerText + profit.innerText + b;
          } else {
              m.innerText = m.innerText - b;
          }
          }



          </script>
        </div>
      </h1>
      <h3>
        <div class="winchance">1 - 6</div>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="inputholder">
      <div id="input">

        <div class="betamount">
          <b>Gems to bet:</b>
        </div>
        <form class="input-money">
          <b><input id="bet" oninput="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="bet" style="color: #404040;" class="form-control" min="0.10" step="any" max="1000.00" value="1.00"></b>
        </form>
        <div class="profitamount">
          <b>Profit:</b>
        </div>
        <div id="profit">
        </div>
        <div id="userchoicetext"><b>Prediction:</b></div>
        <form>
        <input id="userchoice" oninput="edValueKeyPress()" type="number" name="choice" style="color: #404040" class="form-choice" min="1" step="any" max="6" value="1"/>
        </form>
        <button id="playgame" onclick="game()">Throw!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
    function edValueKeyPress(event)
    {
      var input = document.getElementById("bet").value;
      var x = document.getElementById("profit");  // Find the elements
      x.innerText= input * 0.68;    // Change the content
      var n = event.toFixed(2);

    }

  </script>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: What kind of help you need? What is your actual problem?

Comment: your var `bet` is defined as `b` before. so change definition to `var bet = document.getElementsById("bet").value;`

Comment: wow im so stupid thank you haha edit- Still dosen't change the money?

Comment: the console would have told you that! It for sure has shown an error like `bet is undefined`

Comment: No it says value is undefined?

Comment: that's then another error. `getElementsByClassName` return _all_ elements with that classname as an Array, not only the first (and in your case only) one. I guess it's in the line with userchoice?

Comment: Still not fixed it, also i edited the post with the whole code

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors here:

First a simple typo:
You define a variable here

```
var b = document.getElementsById("bet").value;
```

an try to access it as `bet`

```
m.innerText = m.innerText + profit.innerText + bet;
```

Next misstake:
`getElementsById` must be `getElementById`

next:
`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of Nodes, not only the first node it finds, so `var uc = document.getElementsByClassName("userchoice").value;` is an error.

Your debugged code:

```
    var m = document.getElementsByClassName("balance")[0];
    var o = document.getElementById("diceroller");
    var w = document.getElementsByClassName("winchance")[0];
    var uc = document.getElementsByClassName("userchoice")[0].value;

    var bet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("profit");

    function game(event){
       var wn = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
       o.innerText = wn;
       if(uc.value == wn) {
          m.innerText = m.innerText + profit.innerText + bet;
       } else {
          m.innerText = m.innerText - b;
       }
    }
```

I'd highly recommend to give those specific elements an ID and find them via that, rather than a classname.

All these errors are shown in the console - one after each other. Use that to debug your code yourself in the future!

Comment: Thanks, i use the console to find my errors but i get confused :)

Comment: Still get these 2 errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
8dice.php:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: I can't know what line 42 is

Comment: Line 42 is just <h3>

Comment: you have to substract all the php-lines above or look into the generated html file to find the right line

Comment: Hello, sorry i went to sleep, its still broken.